# download github zip file and display contents in web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, scrape, zip

How would you display the contents of a github zip file and display the contents in a web application with the correct file structure?

Could I somehow insert the zip file into the database and then print the contents onto a webpage instead of scraping every single file?

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that you are trying to build a view of the contents of the zipfile similar to Githubs representation, after uploading said zipfile to your server, the easiest way would be to:

1. Use [RubyZip Zip::ZipFile](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/classes/Zip/ZipFile.html) to access the uploaded Zipfile (how to store it as file db depends on your needs).
2. Store the contents in a nested hash and display said hash in a view. The hash can then include drill down links to the extracted files.

To give you a simple example stub how to parse the file (e.g. named test.zip)

```
Zip::ZipFile.open("test.zip") do |zipfile|            
  zipfile.each do |entry|
    # Do something with the enty / create your hash like you need it
  end
end
```

You can find more details in the documentation.

HTH

Comment: Additionally I would recommend to have a look at the css theme of http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/ for a nice directory listing styling too.